# Centos 7 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: generic failure

Tags: centos7, postfix-mta

I've configure the postfix service on Centos 7, but every time i am trying to auth i am getting the same error,

> 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: generic failure

This is the telnet session

```
EHLO localhost 
250-webserverlocaldomain.localdomain 
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000 
250-VRFY 
250-ETRN 
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 
250-8BITMIME 
250 DSN AUTH LOGIN 334
VXNlcm5hbWU6 
bWFpbGVy 
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 
Y29kZW5hbWVkMTU5 
535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: generic failure



This is my etc/postfix/master.cf file
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       n       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       n       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
```

I've tried everything but it is still giving this error. Please help.

Comment: What do your logs say for errors?  Have you turned on debug logging?

Comment: I've installed Centos again and everything works fine.